# Uncaught TypeError: b.ready.promise is not a function

Tags: jquery, migration

I'm trying to migrate a website from jQuery 1.8.3 to 1.9.1, but I have an error that I don't understand. When I changed the version I get these errors:

> Uncaught TypeError: $.widget is not a function
>       at ui.dropdownchecklist.js:11
>       at ui.dropdownchecklist.js:379
>
> Uncaught TypeError: b.ready.promise is not a function
>       at init.ready (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
>       at new init (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
>       at b (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
>       at main.js:18

If you any have an ideas what's causing this it would be great.

Comment: We need to see the code which is generating the errors in order to help you debug them. That being said it's very odd that you're only upgrading to jQuery 1.9.1 as that's still very outdated. You should ideally be looking at moving to 3.3.1

Answer (score 1):

If you are migrating from one jquery Version to another you should always consider the use of their migration plugin. This plugin is specially made for detecting  changes, depreciations etc.
Just add the following tag after your jquery script tag:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.js"></script>
```

Now if you start or serve or whatever your app then you can see errors in your js console in your browser starting with: JQMIGRATE.
Now you just read the error and look it up at this [page](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/1.x-stable/warnings.md).

The page gives you information to each error and how to solve it. This will only help you if your errors have something to do with migration.